# How do I specify what jquery tab to load?

Tags: jquery, tabs

How would I load the second tab in my site instead of the first?

```
  $('.result').load('ajax/test.html');
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#tabs').load('tab2');
  });
```

below is the  some of the HTML...

```
 <div id="tabs"> 
 <ul> 
 <li
        <%= "overview".equals(fundSection) ? " id=\"current\"" : ""%>>
        <netui-compat:anchor action="switchCardTabs">
            <netui-compat:parameter name="tab" value="overview"/>
            <span><i18n:getMessage messageName="portlets.fundcard.section.overview"/></span>
        </netui-compat:anchor>
    </li> 
    <li<%= "performance".equals(fundSection) ? " id=\"current\"" : ""%>>
        <netui-compat:anchor action="switchCardTabs">
            <netui-compat:parameter name="tab" value="performance"/>
            <span><i18n:getMessage messageName="portlets.fundcard.section.performance"/></span>
        </netui-compat:anchor>
    </li> 
    ....
</div>
</div>
```

i dont believe its using the jquery UI, is it still possible to manipulate it?

Comment: Do you mean *select* the second tab? Can you please provide more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's simple, jquery UI tab exposes an option called **selected** you can utilize that on document.ready while initializing the tabs function something like this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: 1 });
  });
```

please note that tab index are 0 based so for second tab we specified 1

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`select`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select) method.

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 'tab2'); // tab ID
// OR
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 1); // tab index (starts at 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using jQuery UI, and that $('#tabs') is initialized as a jQuery UI tabs object elsewhere.

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
```

Comment: thanks, and is it possible to select the tab if im not using jquery UI?
for instance heres my code..

Comment: I tried to follow that link, but it only took me to your user profile.

I don't know why you wouldn't use jQuery if you are using the jQuery UI to create the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
});
```

Untested, but should work.